# How can I delete everything before the first colon in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, parsing, notepad++

I'm trying to get rid of everything before a colon in Notepad++. Column mode is not an option. Is it possible?

#### Input:

```
70.97.110.40:159ms             
70.97.117.177:1.2s            
70.97.120.10:75ms
```

#### Desired output:

```
159ms  
1.2s  
75ms
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with 2 steps:

[image]

The regex: `^.*:`
<kbd>^</kbd> Start of the line
<kbd>.</kbd> Any following character
<kbd>*</kbd> Match any other following character(s)
<kbd>:</kbd> All the way to the colon character

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how in notepad, but regex you're looking for could be

`\d+ms$`

https://regex101.com/r/6QBMbX/1

Answer (score 0):

Here, since it appears that we'd be having whitespaces after `ms` or `s`, we would likely start with an expression such as:

```
.+:(.+[a-z])
```

to be replaced by `$1`.

#### [Please see the demo](https://regex101.com/r/eY6pv7/1/)